# When are the temporary asp.net files cleared from an Azure webapp

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, temporary-files

If you would deploy to a slot and then swap the slots will the temporary asp.net files be cleared? I've seen some issues in azure due to temporary asp.net files. So what I'm wondering is when are the files cleared?

Answer (score 0):

> If you would deploy to a slot and then swap the slots will the temporary asp.net files be cleared?

If you mentioned that temporary files is under the Azure WebApp location `%TMP% goes to D:\local\Temp.`

The short answer is **yes**. If we swap the slot the site worker process will restart. And the files under the temporary folder we be reset to their original state. We could get more information about Swap the azure slot from this [blog](http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/).

> So what I'm wondering is when are the files cleared?
>
> The App Settings and Connection Strings that are marked as "Slot" are read from the Production slot and applied to the site in the Staging slot. That causes the site’s worker process to be restarted for those changes to take effect and become visible as process environment variables;

More information about Azure temporary files, please refer to this [tutorial](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files).

> A number of common Windows locations are using temporary storage on the local machine. For instance
>
> %APPDATA% points to something like D:\local\AppData.
> %TMP% goes to D:\local\Temp.
> Unlike Persisted files, these files are not shared among site instances. Also, you cannot rely on them staying there. For instance, if you **restart** a web app, you'll find that all of these folders get reset to their **original** state.

If mentioned that temporary files is [temporary asp.net files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx).

It will not be deleted during swap. During the swap, just the DNS pointer changed between product and slot. The files under the wwwroot will not changed.

> So what I'm wondering is when are the files cleared?

If it is the secondary scenario, it seems that you need to clear it  by yourself.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify a bit what you mean with if it's the secondary scenario? I can see that there is a d:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ on the webapp, safe to delete wha's beneath the root you think? would this be where the temporary files are stored for the webapp?